# Group by Rolling max look forward

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find highest price of stock in next 10 trading sessions.

```
    Date    Symbol  Average Expected Value
3505    03-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  38.054  42.24
3506    04-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  38.35   42.24
3507    05-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  37.981  42.24
3508    06-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  37.988  42.24
3509    07-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  38.338  42.98
3510    10-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  41.497  
3511    11-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  41.251  
3512    12-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  42.146  
3513    13-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  42.24   
3514    14-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  41.005  
3515    17-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  41.372  
3516    18-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  41.376  
3517    19-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  42.193  
3518    20-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  41.878  
3519    21-01-2000  ASIANPAINT  42.977  
8994    03-01-2000  AXISBANK    5.34    5.448
8995    04-01-2000  AXISBANK    5.448   5.254
8996    05-01-2000  AXISBANK    5.248   5.254
8997    06-01-2000  AXISBANK    5.254   5.112
8998    07-01-2000  AXISBANK    5.008   5.112
8999    10-01-2000  AXISBANK    5.058   
9000    11-01-2000  AXISBANK    4.78    
9001    12-01-2000  AXISBANK    4.794   
9002    13-01-2000  AXISBANK    4.754   
9003    14-01-2000  AXISBANK    4.634   
9004    17-01-2000  AXISBANK    5.018   
9005    18-01-2000  AXISBANK    4.988   
9006    19-01-2000  AXISBANK    5.112   
9007    20-01-2000  AXISBANK    5.01    
9008    21-01-2000  AXISBANK    4.958
```

Data in csv format

```
Date,Symbol,Average,Expected Value
03-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,38.054,42.24
04-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,38.35,42.24
05-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,37.981,42.24
06-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,37.988,42.24
07-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,38.338,42.98
10-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,41.497,
11-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,41.251,
12-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,42.146,
13-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,42.24,
14-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,41.005,
17-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,41.372,
18-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,41.376,
19-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,42.193,
20-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,41.878,
21-01-2000,ASIANPAINT,42.977,
03-01-2000,AXISBANK,5.34,5.448
04-01-2000,AXISBANK,5.448,5.254
05-01-2000,AXISBANK,5.248,5.254
06-01-2000,AXISBANK,5.254,5.112
07-01-2000,AXISBANK,5.008,5.112
10-01-2000,AXISBANK,5.058,
11-01-2000,AXISBANK,4.78,
12-01-2000,AXISBANK,4.794,
13-01-2000,AXISBANK,4.754,
14-01-2000,AXISBANK,4.634,
17-01-2000,AXISBANK,5.018,
18-01-2000,AXISBANK,4.988,
19-01-2000,AXISBANK,5.112,
20-01-2000,AXISBANK,5.01,
21-01-2000,AXISBANK,4.958,
```

I have tried so far

```
all_scripts_df.Average[::-1].rolling(window=10).max()[::-1][:15]
```

But this approach will consider current trading session as well. also group by will be little difficult.

Other approach I tried is

```
all_scripts_df.groupby('Symbol').rolling(10, min_periods=1)['Average'].max().reset_index().head(10)
```

But this approach looks back value and not look forward.

Comment: Can you format the data part so that it is clearly visible, unable to comprehend it. Also unable to understand what you are trying to achieve. What type of data is that a string? JSON ? List ? Pandas DF ?

Comment: @PranavSR it is pandas df. first column is index, so you can ignore it. let me paste in csv format.

Comment: yes please do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a double `groupby`:

```
df['Value'] = df.groupby('Symbol').rolling(10, min_periods=1)['Average'].max() \
                .groupby(level=0).shift(-10).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
           Date      Symbol  Average   Value
3505 2000-03-01  ASIANPAINT   38.054  42.240
3506 2000-04-01  ASIANPAINT   38.350  42.240
3507 2000-05-01  ASIANPAINT   37.981  42.240
3508 2000-06-01  ASIANPAINT   37.988  42.240
3509 2000-07-01  ASIANPAINT   38.338  42.977
3510 2000-10-01  ASIANPAINT   41.497     NaN
3511 2000-11-01  ASIANPAINT   41.251     NaN
3512 2000-12-01  ASIANPAINT   42.146     NaN
3513 2000-01-13  ASIANPAINT   42.240     NaN
3514 2000-01-14  ASIANPAINT   41.005     NaN
3515 2000-01-17  ASIANPAINT   41.372     NaN
3516 2000-01-18  ASIANPAINT   41.376     NaN
3517 2000-01-19  ASIANPAINT   42.193     NaN
3518 2000-01-20  ASIANPAINT   41.878     NaN
3519 2000-01-21  ASIANPAINT   42.977     NaN
8994 2000-03-01    AXISBANK    5.340   5.448
8995 2000-04-01    AXISBANK    5.448   5.254
8996 2000-05-01    AXISBANK    5.248   5.254
8997 2000-06-01    AXISBANK    5.254   5.112
8998 2000-07-01    AXISBANK    5.008   5.112
8999 2000-10-01    AXISBANK    5.058     NaN
9000 2000-11-01    AXISBANK    4.780     NaN
9001 2000-12-01    AXISBANK    4.794     NaN
9002 2000-01-13    AXISBANK    4.754     NaN
9003 2000-01-14    AXISBANK    4.634     NaN
9004 2000-01-17    AXISBANK    5.018     NaN
9005 2000-01-18    AXISBANK    4.988     NaN
9006 2000-01-19    AXISBANK    5.112     NaN
9007 2000-01-20    AXISBANK    5.010     NaN
9008 2000-01-21    AXISBANK    4.958     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function for avoid double `groupby`:

```
df['Value'] = (df.groupby('Symbol')['Average']
                 .transform(lambda x: x.rolling(10, min_periods=1).max().shift(-10)))
```